# Creating Angular5 application how reuse this in IONIC 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

Please suggest me for the following questions.

1. Is there a way to reuse the Angular5 app to create mobile app using IONIC 3.
2. Please let me know if we can reuse this Angular Web app in IONIC 3 then what are the recommendations we should follow for it.

Note:
The web app html pages are fully responsive.
Mine is just a simple application, it's not a game app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would create a mobile application in Ionic and then host it as a SPA on the web. (You can preview this by creating a new ionic application and then viewing it in your browser via `ionic cordova run browser`)

You could copy the files over to the src/app directory and update the needed package.json entries.

If you run into a specific error you can post it as a question, but I'm running Angular 5 in two Ionic apps without issue.

Comment: How are you adding the push notifications on this kind of mobile app?

Comment: I've done two apps with different kinds of push notifications. The first used firebase and didn't care that it was an ionic app. The second used Ionic Pro services, which let me push background updates, etc.

Comment: This may be not related to the post I just have one last question, my angular5 application is more about front office application, will this Cordova approach works seamlessly and without making any bad user experience?

Comment: Cordova is a technology that helps you write code once (in ionic) and have it translated to whatever the platform needs (desktop app, web app, android, ios, etc.) The only time I've seen a difference is when using Ionic Native plugins. Ionic's website list each of those plugins and which platforms they work on. As an example, I can track if the user shakes the phone in android, but there is no such feature in web mode